# Small Jquery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JQUERY script running on [www.blisshair.com.au](http://www.blisshair.com.au).

The script sets the 3 left hand div's as sticky, i.e when the user scrolls the divs follow.
I have been trying to get jquery to find the height on a div called wholewrap (which as the name implies is the wrapper for the whole site). 
Once I have got that value I would like to see if it is smaller then a certain value (at the moment I am trying 1500px - trial and error to see which one works).
If the height of wholewrap is smaller then my predetermined size then I would like the setting2 variable to reflect one size, else reflect the other size.

Here is the code I have. All I would like this to do is set the height of setting2 to the height of the div wholewrap (to stop the overflow issue on www.blisshair.com.au) I have added the whole JS file as I am unsure where it is all going wrong :

```
function StickyScroller(obj, options)
{        
//Store function scope
var $this = this;

//Store initial top and left/right values
var top = $(obj).css('top');
var left = $(obj).css('left');
var right = $(obj).css('right');

var scroll = 0;
var tempScroll = 0;

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Set default property values
//------------------------------------------------------------
var defaults = {
start: 0,
end: 1000,
interval: 400,
margin: parseInt(top, 10),
range: 400
},  settings = jQuery.extend(defaults,options);
obj = $(obj);

settings.index = 0;
settings.oldIndex = 0;

//Accessors for settings
GetSet.getters({scope: $this, obj: settings});

//------------------------------------------------------------//
//                      Callback Functions                    //
//------------------------------------------------------------//
var Callback = {};

Callback.newIndex = function(){};  //When the index changes
Callback.limbo = function(){};     //When scroller not in range
Callback.scroll = function(){};    //On window scroll

//Get setters for Callback functions
GetSet.setters({scope: this, prefix: "on", obj: Callback});   

//=========================================================//
//Public distanceFrom
//Purpose: Determines the distance in pixels between
//         the scroller and an index
//Parameters:
//  index: The index whose distance from scroller will be calculated
//Postcondition: Returns an integer
//=========================================================//
this.distanceFrom = function(index)
{        
    tempScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    //Check for both references: "Top" of the range and "bottom"
    var top = index*settings.interval;
    var bottom = index*settings.interval + settings.range;

    var distanceFromTop = Math.abs(tempScroll-top);
    var distanceFromBottom = Math.abs(tempScroll-bottom);

    //Return the smallest distance
    if(distanceFromTop < distanceFromBottom)
    {
        return distanceFromTop;
    }
    else
    {
        return distanceFromBottom;
    }        
};

var whwrap = $("#wholewrap").height();
var wrap2 = $("#wrap2").height();
var mwrapEDIT = $("#middlewrap").height();
var mwrap = (mwrapEDIT * .8);

if(whwrap < 1500)
    {
        var setting2 = wrap2;
    }
    else
    {
        var setting2 = mwrap;
    }   




//=========================================================//
//Public closestIndex
//Purpose: Determines the closest index
//Postcondition: Returns the closest index as an integer
//=========================================================//
this.closestIndex = function()
{
    //If index is 0, automatically return 1
    if(settings.index === 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }        

    //Distance from next/previous index
    var dPrev = this.distanceFrom(settings.index-1);
    var dNext = this.distanceFrom(settings.index+1);

    //Return the index associated with the smallest distance
    if(dPrev <= dNext)
    {
        return settings.index-1;
    }
    else
    {
        return settings.index+1;
    }
};

//=========================================================//
//Private getIndex
//Purpose: returns index
//=========================================================//
var getIndex = function()
{        
    tempScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + settings.margin;        

    //Make sure movement would be in the bounds
    if(tempScroll > settings.start && tempScroll < setting2)
    {                                       
        //Possible new index
        tempIndex = Math.floor((tempScroll-settings.start)/settings.interval);

        //Make sure the index is different before reassigning
        //or executing the callback
        if(tempIndex !== settings.index)
        {
            //Store old index
            settings.oldIndex = settings.index;                

            //Assign new index
            settings.index = tempIndex;                
        }
    }
    //If tempScroll goes beyond end mark, set distance at end mark
    else if(tempScroll >= setting2)
    {
        settings.oldIndex = settings.index;
        settings.index = Math.floor((setting2-settings.start)/settings.interval);
    }
    //If tempScroll goes beyond beginning mark, set distance at start
    else
    {
        settings.oldIndex = settings.index;
        settings.index = 0;
    }        
};

//=========================================================//
//Public firstIndex
//Purpose: Returns first index
//Postcondition: Returns an integer
//=========================================================//
this.firstIndex = function()
{
    return 0;
};

//=========================================================//
//Public lastIndex
//Purpose: Returns last index
//Postcondition: Returns an integer
//=========================================================//
this.lastIndex = function()
{
    return Math.floor((setting2-settings.start)/settings.interval);
};

//=========================================================//
//Public inRange
//Purpose: Determines if the scroller is in interval range
//Postcondition: Returns boolean
//=========================================================//
this.inRange = function()
{      
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() - settings.start + settings.margin;        

    var inRange = (scroll >= settings.index * settings.interval) &&
    (scroll <= (settings.index*settings.interval + settings.range));

    return inRange;
};


//------------------------------------------------------------//
//                    On Browser Scroll                       //
//------------------------------------------------------------//    
var wrap = $('<div id="scrollcontainer">').css(
{
    width: obj.width(),
    height: obj.height(),
    position: "absolute"
});

obj.wrap(wrap);

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + settings.margin;

    //Get the current index
    getIndex();

    //If scroll less than beginning, set back to beginning
    if(scroll < settings.start)
    {
       $(obj).css({
        position : 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0});

       $("#scrollcontainer").css({
        position : 'absolute',
        top: settings.start,
        left: left,
        right: right});
    }

    //If scroll greater than ending position, set to end
    else if(scroll > setting2) 
    {
       $(obj).css({
        position : 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0});

       $("#scrollcontainer").css({
        position : 'absolute',
        top: setting2,
        left: left,
        right: right});

    }

    //Make sure we stay in the specified boundaries
    else
    {
        //Put back to fixed
        $(obj).css({
        position : 'fixed',
        top: settings.margin,
        left: left,
        right: right});
    }        

    //If in the specified range and a new index, do the callback        
    if(settings.oldIndex !== settings.index)
    {
       Callback.newIndex(settings.index);
    }

    //Do the "limbo" call back, which is a callback that executes when
    //the scroller is not in the range, but still between start and end
    if( !$this.inRange() && scroll > settings.start && scroll < setting2 )
    {
       Callback.limbo(settings.index);
    }

    //Do the scroll callback regardless of what happens
    Callback.scroll(settings.index);
});
```

}

Am I on the right track?

Thanks.

Comment: It's working just fine for me on Google Chrome.

Comment: Just downloaded chrome to see and it has the same issue. When scrolling to the very bottom of page, the 3rd left div overlaps into the footer. My screen resolution is 1280 * 1024

Comment: It is more noticeable on http://blisshair.com.au/bookonline.php

Comment: `outerWidth` and `outerHight` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

By the way, is there a reason you haven't considered a CSS solution? The CSS below seems to resolve the problem:

```
div#menuwrap {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 5%;
}
```

Looking over your site (in Google Chrome, running at 1440 x 900):

- You have 5 divs with `id="rnd_container"` (the `id` attribute should be unique for each element).
- You have 5 divs with `id="contentimages"`
- You have 3 divs with `id="block"`
- You've got a case mismatch on an `h3` tag (`<h3>15/1/12 - Bliss Online launched!</H3>` should be `<h3>15/1/12 - Bliss Online launched!</h3>`). This can prevent proper tag closing (which causes problems).

Above are what I would consider to be the big problems, but you can see all of the validation errors at: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blisshair.com.au%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

I would also make sure that `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` is the first script loaded.

On http://blisshair.com.au/bookonline.php, `<div id="right">...</div>` has a width of 745px and a margin-left of 220px. The margin-left is what is causing the funkiness. If you change that to 22px, it looks fine. Alternatively, you can change the width of div#right to 57%, or 558px and it will work too.

As far as fixing the overflow problem with the footer (and as `setting2` relates to it), `$("#wholewrap").height()` is returning 2597px so your arbitrary 1500px limit will never be reached. Further, `<div id="footer" class="clearer">` is a child of `<div id="wholewrap">`. Ergo, the height of `div#footer` is part of the height of `div#wholewrap`, so I'm not sure that changing `setting2` will fix the problem.

How do you want the "overflow issue" to be solved? Do you want `div#middlewrap` to scroll up when `div#footer` is on the screen? Do you want `div#footer` shifted to the right? Something else? Please clarify how the issue should be solved.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, posted the question just before sleeping. I would like the 3 divs on the left hand (menu and 2 ads) side to scroll down until they reach the footer, stopping without any overflow whatsoever, hopefully without having to move middlewrap or footer, 
I was hoping that #wrap2 (which is a child of #menuwrap (which should inherit its height from #middlewrap which in turn is the same height as #right) would be able to scroll the height of menuwrap.

Comment: Also thanks for the info on the validations, will get them corrected asap

Comment: Hi, originally it was all done with CSS, yet I noticed that whenever the window was resized the left menu would overlap the footer, exactly what is happening now.

Comment: I am goig to award this win the answer, even though it didnt solve the problem, I have since decided that the sticky menu is way to much trouble then it is worth and will be going with a more traditional, static approach. Thanks all for reading.